# Getting null value in Action from Ajax request in Struts 2

Tags: ajax, json, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I am trying to send AJAX request to Action in which I am sending one parameter from JSP page. So my Action class is receiving the Ajax request but params which I am sending with AJAX class are `null` in `Action` class.

**This is My Action Class:**

```
 public class AjaxAction{

String name;
private  String welcomeMessage;

public String execute(){

    System.out.println("AJax called "+name);
    welcomeMessage="Hello"+name;
    return "success";
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getWelcomeMessage() {
    return welcomeMessage;
}

public void setWelcomeMessage(String welcomeMessage) {
    this.welcomeMessage = welcomeMessage;
}
 }
```

**This is my `struts.xml` file:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
     "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
     "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
 <struts>

 <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="json" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="json">
                <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>
    
            <action name="ajaxAction" class="com.action.AjaxAction">
                <result type="json"/>
            </action>
    </package>
```

**This is my Jsp file:**

```
<title>Struts Ajax Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxStruts() {
        data = {
                name:$("#name").val(),
            };

            alert(data);
            $.ajax({
                  type: 'GET',
                  contentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                  url:'ajaxAction',
                  data: $("#ajaxform").serialize(),
                  success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                  }
                
            });
        
    }
</script>

 </head>
 <body>

<fieldset>
    <form method="POST" id="ajaxform">
        Name::<input type="text" id="name" name="name"> 
         <input type="button" name="submit"
            value="submit" onclick="return ajaxStruts();">
    </form>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <div id="ajaxResult"></div>
</fieldset>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your interceptors in `struts.xml`.

Either remove them or specify them properly. You have override `defaultstack` Which is not good practice.

**You should make your interceptor-stack's name as custom name different from struts stacks.**

**For Example**, name your stack as mystack.

```
 <interceptors>
    <interceptor-stack name="mystack">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="json">
            <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
    </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
```

This means all the interceptors of `defaultstack` + json interceptor. This will be packed in interceptor stack named as mystack

Comment: Thanks @parth ...it is working! Can you provide me some tutorial link for reference

Comment: yes sure... for struts2 [Click here](http://www.javatpoint.com/struts-2-tutorial) and For json example [See this example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-and-json-example/) .. And if you are new user to stack overflow then I will suggest you to learn how to accept answer [Click here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @Hitesh Refer this link for json and struts2. http://tech.learnerandtutor.com/send-json-object-to-struts-2-action-by-jquery-ajax/
http://tech.learnerandtutor.com/read-json-object-from-struts-2-action-by-jquery-ajax/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a custom interceptor stack and make it as default interceptor stack you can do it in the following way but putting [`json` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/json/) in front of your stack, however it gives you nothing unless you send data in json format.

```
<interceptors>
    <interceptor-stack name="jsonDefaultStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="json">
            <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
    </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>

<default-interceptor-ref name="jsonDefaultStack" />
```

The default stack of interceptors contains a functionality to populate your action bean with parameters that you should send as `POST` request.

```
function ajaxStruts() {
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          url: "<s:url action='ajaxAction' namespace='/'/>",
          dataType: "json",
          data: $("#ajaxform").serialize(),
          success: function(data){
            alert(data);
          }
    });
}
```